# Can I write a function that checks if an answer pressed by a user clicked is true or false and load the new question once it is done?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a simple online quiz game using HTML, CSS and JavaScript.
My current issue is that I am trying to write a function that checks if the answer the used clicked is true or false and load the new question once it is done. Is there something I am missing from my code here?

```
function selectAnswer(e) {
    console.log("I'm here!")
    const selectedButton = e.target;
    const correct = selectedButton.dataset.correct;
    checkAnswers(document.newButton, correct)
    Array.from(answerButtonsElement.children).forEach(newButton => {
      checkAnswers(newButton, newButton.dataset.correct)
    })
    if (shuffledQuestions.length > currentQuestionIndex + 1) {
      submitButtonElement.classList.remove('hide')
    } else {
      startButton.innerText = 'Restart'
      startButton.classList.remove('hide')
    }
  

}

function checkAnswers(element, correct) {
    resetPage
    if (correct === true) {
        element.classList.add('correct-btn');
    } else {
        element.classList.add('incorrect-btn');
    }
}


function resetPage(element) {
    element.classList.remove('correct-btn')
    element.classList.remove('incorrect-btn')

}
```

Comment: You gave the description of your task, not your issue. What doesn't work in your code?

Answer (score 0):

in the Function "checkAnswers" you are calling the function "resetPage"
without giving any variable and without also parenthesis.

in this function:

```
function checkAnswers(element, correct) {
    resetPage(element)
    if (correct === true) {
        element.classList.add('correct-btn');
    } else {
        element.classList.add('incorrect-btn');
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).